# Wordpress apply color scheme by category name

Tags: css, wordpress

Is there a simple way I could apply different color scheme css based on category names in wordpress? For example I have a green.css which changes h2 and block color, I want to apply this when category = green. Is there a solution or addon for this? I'm using multisite.

Comment: How do you want to apply a different color scheme? Do you want to load a different CSS file, or add a class to the body (ex, add the 'theme-green' class), or some other way?

Comment: @emmzee yes, load different css file. i.e. green.css

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this does what you want:

Without knowing exactly how your theme is set up, you can add something like the following to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function load_css_theme(){
    $categories = get_the_category();
    if (!empty($categories)) {
        foreach($categories as $c) {
            if ($c->name === 'green') {
                wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/green.css');
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'load_css_theme');
```

It will check the categories for the current page; if the category "green" is found, it will enqueue the green.css file. (This assumes the green.css file is in the root of the theme folder.) You can add more themes by adding more "if" statements like the example, just changing the category and the css filename.